# Umbraco Exmine engine return duplicate results after modifying a document

Tags: umbraco, lucene.net, umbraco6, examine

I'm using Examine to search in website content,
But whenever an article is updated, it is shown more than once in the result, with same count as the number of modifications !!

```
      <IndexSet SetName ="ArabicIndexerIndexSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Arabic/">
        <IndexUserFields>
          <add Name="id" EnableSorting="true" Type="Number" />
          <add Name="content" EnableSorting="true" />
          <add Name="author" EnableSorting="true" />
          <add Name="title" EnableSorting="true" />
          <add Name="description" EnableSorting="true" />
          <add Name ="umbracoNaviHide"/>
        </IndexUserFields>
      </IndexSet>



  <ExamineSearchProviders defaultProvider="ArabicSearcher">
    <providers>

<add name="ArabicSearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine" 
           indexSet="ArabicIndexerIndexSet"
           supportUnpublished="false" 
           supportProtected="false"
           analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR.ArabicAnalyzer, Lucene.Net.Contrib.Analyzers"/>

    </providers>
  </ExamineSearchProviders>
```

and this is my query:

```
+((title:Test Phrase content:Test Phrase)) +(umbracoNaviHide:0)
```

How to solve this?

EDIT:
Rebuilding the index solves the problem temporarily, and once you modify the article again, the problem appears again.

EDIT2:

I used Luke to investigate the problem, the only difference is the update date between the duplicated results.
See the image:
[image: Results]

EDIT3:
I found a solution that worked, but I'm not convinced with it here: [Index is not updated automatically](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/21229-Examine-Index-is-not-updated-automatically)

which suggests to use the follwing code:

```
public class UmbracoEvents: ApplicationBase
{
  /// <summary>Constructor</summary>
  public UmbracoEvents()
  {
    umbraco.content.AfterUpdateDocumentCache += new umbraco.content.DocumentCacheEventHandler(content_AfterUpdateDocumentCache);
  }

 privatevoid content_AfterUpdateDocumentCache(Document sender, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.DocumentCacheEventArgs e)
 {
   // Rebuild SiteSearchIndexer (Search results will be updated after a few minutes)
   ExamineManager.Instance.IndexProviderCollection["SiteSearchIndexer"].RebuildIndex();
 }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it takes a long time to rebuild the index with large amount of content! (10000 documents in my case) and during the index rebuild process, the user will get 0 result searching anything, which confuses the user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your search query is incorrectly structured. If you are searching for the phrase "Test Phrase" in the title and content property, your query should be:

```
+(title:Test Phrase content:Test Phrase) +(umbracoNaviHide:0)
```

Comment: I want to get any article that either its title or its content contains the phrase (Test Phrase).
And if the query is wrong, why it returns an old version of the same article in addition to the new version?

Comment: Ok, I've amended. Are you including the curly brackets {} in your search query?

Comment: No, I'm not, and I'll try the query you mentioned.

Comment: You should amend your question to remove the curly brackets. My answer is the same as yours in that case. Have you tried using Luke to investigate? http://www.getopt.org/luke/

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the question, it was because of copying the value from Visual Studio.
Regarding Luke, I already tried to read the index with it, but didn't know where to start, I couldn't search for more than one field at time !
In addition to that Luke doesn't have the Arabic Analyzer.
One more thing, I tried to rebuild the index, and it worked !
But whenever I modify and republish, the same error occurs again.

Comment: No problem, easily done. You should be able to create and amend your search query in the Search tab of Luke, and select the Arabic Analyzer from the dropdown on the right hand side. Do you have any custom Examine Events running that might be interfering?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58987/discussion-between-nour-sabouny-and-ollie-p).